# Chef rpm_package throws error installing from local source

Tags: java, chef-infra

I'm using Chef 12.5.1 and the Docker image Test-Kitchen is running is running RHEL 7.x

I download jdk-8u65-linux-x64.rpm to a local directory on my Docker test instance and run the following recipe to install it.

```
rpm_package 'install_java' do
  package_name 'jdk-8u65-linux-x64.rpm'
  source '/home/user/jdk-8u65-linux-x64.rpm'
end
```

But it throws the following error:

```
---- Begin output of rpm  -i /home/user/jdk-8u65-linux-x64.rpm ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: error: Failed dependencies:
   /usr/bin/find is needed by jdk1.8.0_65-2000:1.8.0_65-fcs.x86_64
---- End output of rpm  -i /home/user/jdk-8u65-linux-x64.rpm ----
```

The only information I could find was this [comment](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2003-February/msg00002.html) but I tried "chmod +x" on the RPM and it didn't help.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rpm` on its own isn't capable of installing dependencies, normally this would be handled by `yum`. You can either install the RPM with `yum` or find a package to fulfill the dependency (probably `find` or `findutils`) and install it.

Comment: Are you testing under the same circumstances? The only time I would expect `find` to not be installed is a minimalist Docker image which will behave differently than a stock EL install.

Comment: I'm very surprised by this but apparently this is a very minimal Docker RHEL 7 image.  There was no /usr/bin/find on it.  Thank you, I think if I change the image that should fix the problem.

Comment: Or just install via `yum` instead or `rpm` so it can fix the deps for you :)